# Are these following integration equal?

Tags: measure-theory

Is the statement true?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_X f_n(x)dx=\int_X\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)dx$$

Comment: It is not true neither false. It's a formula without context, and it could be true under some conditions, false under other conditions.

Comment: Not in general. One can specify conditions on the $f_n$ (look up the Monotone and Dominated Convergence Theorems) that make it true for those.

Comment: If this were always true, then why would the all the various convergence theorems for integrals exist?

Comment: If fn is a monotonic increasing sequence of functions with limit f, is it true? And if fn -> f pointwise and |fn|<=g for an integrable g, is it true?

Comment: @Yuteng Yes in both cases: these are the monotone convergence theorem and dominated convergence theorem, respectively.(However, for the monotone convergence theorem you need the additional hypothesis that each $f_n$ is nonnegative.)

Answer (score 3):

Passing a limit through an integral (which is what you are doing) is delicate.  You have to know something about the sequence of functions that you are working with.  Without additional hypotheses, the statement just isn't true.  For example, let $f_n : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$ f_n := \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[0,n]}. $$
Observe that $f_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function, therefore
$$ \int \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = \int 0 = 0.$$
On the other hand,
$$ \int f_n = 1 $$
for all $n$, and so
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n = 1.$$
In this example, we can't pass the limit through the integral.

However, there are cases when this is possible.  For example, if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative functions such that $f_m(x) \le f_n(x)$ for all $x$ and for all $n>m$, then we can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem (which, if you are studying measure theory, you should encounter fairly early on) to pass the limit through the integral.  Or, if there is some function $g$ that dominates all of the $f_n$ (i.e. $g(x) \ge |f_n(x)|$ for all $x$ and $n$), and
$$ \int g < \infty, $$
then we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem (ditto---you should see this early on if you are studying measure theory) and pass a limit through an integral.  Other theorems apply if, for instance, the space you are integrating over has finite measure.

In short, a large part of introductory measure theory is determining exactly when it is okay to bring limits into integrals.

Comment: Neat example! Thanks!